# Webapp to convert all dates in an unstructured text to a different timezone

Tags: gratis, web-apps, time-management, nlp, timezones

Is there a webapp that could **convert all of dates/times in a text**?

For instance, I received an email like this:

> We could talk on Wed 5/25 at 1-3pm, 5-8pm, or 10-11:30pm. Or how about Thu 5/26 1-4pm or 5pm-9pm?

It is a pain to convert all of these to my timezone.

Requirements:

- Ability to choose the writer's timezone and my own
- Freely usable, no registration

Converting only times (and ignoring dates) is acceptable too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Javascript you could use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and write yourself a simple script that will accept different formats of dates and convert them for you.